# Function declared as Virtual in derived class doesn't execute, instead gave compilation error, Why?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions, vtable, static-typing

I am understanding the virtual function and vTable, so pls excuse if its a trivial question to ask....

Based on the concept of vTable and vPtr explained by people, I understood and expect that below program should work but its giving error.

**Problem Statement:**
In the example below, as per understanding class B should have a "vTable" containing function f2() and f3(). Isn't it?
(since f2() is inherited from class A but overridden and f3 is made virtual in the class B itself)

but when making a function call " **obj->f3();** " its giving error as below, I am still wondering why is it so?

ERROR :
In function 'int main()':
31:10: error: 'class A' has no member named 'f3'

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;     
class A
{
    public:
    void f1() {cout<<"A::f1"<<endl;}
    virtual void f2() {cout<<"A::f2"<<endl;}
};    

class B: public A
{
    public:
    void f1() {cout<<"B::f1"<<endl;}
    void f2() {cout<<"B::f2"<<endl;}
    virtual void f3() {cout<<"B::f3"<<endl;}
};


int main()
{
    A* obj = new B();
    obj->f1();      // Early Binding (EB)
    obj->f2();      // Late Binding (LB)
    obj->f3();      // Error (though was expecting LB since f3 is virtual)
}
```

**ERROR** :
*In function 'int main()': 31:10: error: 'class A' has no member named 'f3'*

Comment: `f3()` is not a member of `A`. The End.

Comment: Where in vtable of A would f3 be stored?

Comment: You cannot add new virtual members to a base class in derived classes.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, thanks for the answer. Probably I may have some misconception about vTable understanding so pls correct me if I am wrong.

I have studied that, at runtime the type of object which pointer A is pointing is evaluated and the vTable of that class i.e. class B is chosen to figure out the  called function f3().

Since class B vTable must be having B::f3() in vTable, it was my assumption that compiler would call it but it gave error which confused me.

Comment: Learning floating point (fp) arithmetic must be done with a correct understanding of the representation of fp types and the limits of precision implied by that representation. The representation of fp types cannot be abstracted. You just cannot skip that. Learning the use of virtual functions doesn't imply understanding the details of vtables (vtables are used by 100% of C++ compilers) because the semantics of virtual functions are best described in term of abstract semantics as a function of the **type of objects**. You also need to understand the **type of expressions** (syntax constructs).

Answer (score 3):

The implementation details (vtable or not) don't matter. In the eyes of the standard (and thus the compiler) your code is invalid because `A` doesn't have a method `f3()` and `obj` is of type `A*`, that's it.

Comment: Your answer is not so clear to me. I am trying to understand the concept of late binding in this context. Pls correct me if my understanding is incorrect and help me get it right.

If you mean that during the compilation, compiler first checks for the type of 'obj' which is A* in this case and first tries to look for f3() method.

if it finds a concrete function f3(), then compiler will bind it there itself otherwise, if f3() is declared as virtual in class A, then compiler defers the binding to be done at run-time?

but since the class doesn't have f3(). it failed during compilation.

Comment: @PrinceRambade Names are bound at compile time. Always.

Answer (score 0):

Before trying to describe the semantics of any C++ instruction, you need to go back to the most fundamental concepts of C++ (which are a sophisticated variant of the fundamental concepts of C): **C++ is a compiled language with static typing**.

Like in C, in C++ **names are looked-up and bound at compile time**: any name used must refer to a visible declaration. The only names that can be found by the compiler are those in the class designated by the expression. (Expressions are syntax constructs, they exist at *compile time*.)

In a statically typed language, **types of expressions** are static and are computed inside in each function according to the declarations.

C++ also supports dynamic polymorphic via virtual functions; that doesn't make the language dynamically typed; the fundamentals are unchanged: each expressions has a type determined by applying rules based on its syntax and on visible declarations (visible names of objects, functions, etc.).

With dynamic polymorphic **the type of a polymorphic object** (objects exist at *run time*), that is the type that was constructed (the name of the class of the constructor that ran to construct the object) **determines which function body is invoked by a virtual call**. That's sometimes called late binding.

Late binding isn't the issue here in your ill-formed code that doesn't even compile, doesn't run, and doesn't call any function at  run time on any polymorphic object:

```
obj->f3();      // Error (though was expecting LB since f3 is virtual)
```

When `obj` has pointer type `obj->something` is the same as `(*obj).something`; and `obj` is a local variable defined as

```
A* obj = (...something not relevant for the argument...);
```

so `obj` has type `A*` and `*obj` has type `A` which is a class defined as:

```
class A
{
    public:
    void f1() {cout<<"A::f1"<<endl;}
    virtual void f2() {cout<<"A::f2"<<endl;}
};
```

There is no declaration of any member `f3` visible in the class designated by the expression `*obj`. **So the call is ill formed.** It is invalid at compile time and the compiler rejects it.

And that is *the entirety of the relevant analysis* of that ill formed line. The rest doesn't matter in a statically typed language. Derived classes not named in the *relevant* code (which is just the declared type of `obj` and the expression which determines where name lookup is done, `*obj`) do not matter. This is the *essence* of static typing.

Also, making the validity of the code dependent on other classes not named directly (classes that may be the type of the object constructed at run time that some expression refers to) would make the detection of even a simple typo impossible at compile time.